# What's the proper API/SDK to use for a CMS offering an integrated Shopping Cart with PayPal Payments (3rd party)

Tags: php, paypal

we are working on a new Shopping-Cart-Solution which will be part of our Desktop-CMS which customers buy to build their websites, and publish it onto their own hosting accounts. The Cart is PHP-Based and hosted on our customers respective website. Most customers are based in the EU.

We want to offer a similar level of integration as e.g. Shopify does. I guess that'd involve, that we setup a PayPal APP and then, later in the process, the customer using our software would grant out PayPal App access, so we can process orders on his behalf. Correct?

I haven't been able to find any good quickstart documentation on the PayPal site, so i'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction as to which SKK/API to use and wether it is possible, to ask out customer to grant permission from inside an Windows-APP (not a Website).

Reading the Docs it also wasn't clear to me, how we'd handle transactions in the name of our customers. Would that happen by using `payee` and `payer` entities?

I'd also love to get in touch with PayPals "Solution Providers" department, but haven't found any method of contact, so if you know how, please let me know.

Thanks for any pointers!